# Nginx reverse proxy docker behind apache not working

Tags: php, apache, docker, nginx, proxy

On my single VPS host I've already an apache with websites. I want to keep it and have an docker with this nginx-proxy with subdomain. Later i will migrate everything in docker .

1. Apache run on port:80 , 443
2. nginx-proxy runs on port 81 using jwilder/nginx-proxy docker .
3. subdomain.domain.com maps to server IP : 109.xxx.xx.xx

Apache is serving content correctly .

nginx-proxy runs smoothly on port 81 .

```
docker run -d --name nginx-proxy -p 81:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Then i run my sub domain container as suggested [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

```
docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=crawling.domain.com -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8181  --volume /home/vps/crawling/crawling/:/var/www/html  --detach --publish 8181:80 crawling
```

[image: Docker running container]

Now problem is when use **http://subdomain.domain.com** it redirects to server ip (109.xxx.xx.xx) home where some dummy index page is used .

Currently i can't change apache port as it will effect many serving content.

EDIT :

as @Tarun suggest i need to pass proxy from Apache to nginx docker . Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: I think think you can't use the jwilder-proxy image to proxy the apache on your host.

Comment: I have Apache installed in my VPS with PHP already serving some content . I need nginx to serve some docker to my subdomain .

Comment: You are running nginx on 81 and expecting it to service a subdomain on port 80. How?

Comment: @TarunLalwani then according to your suggestion either i remove Apache or niginx

Comment: You can have both also, but then you will need add config to Apache to ProxyPass subdomain.domain.com to port 81 where nginx will handle it

Comment: Ohh ! Can you explain bit more in answer